# Vertical scrolling does not work with embedded iframe, however horizontal works ok (without jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll

I am unable to scroll vertically when using dynamically added iframe. Horizontally works ok. I have seen some questions and answers, however, neither of them works for me.
Also i dont want to use jquery, i am sure that this can be done by using just scrollTo and scrollBy.
I want to scroll to the bottom when specific action is done.

```
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe"); 
   var url = <PAGE>;
   ifrm.setAttribute("src", url);
   ifrm.style.width = 1280 +"px";
   ifrm.style.height = 1720 +"px"; //for testing, hardcoded               
   document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

   window.scrollTo(0, 500);
```

When i put window.scrollTo(500, 500); everything is ok, page is scrolled right for 500.
Does anybody see any issue in my code?

This is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/aLvgx/5/

update 1: changed "my_frame" to "iframe" in createElement. Copying code error.

update 2: when i start this page (code: http://pastebin.com/dCRQkQj9) in chrome, i get this values: 
 H: 947
 W: 1861 It is possible to automatically scroll horizontally, but vertically not.

Comment: please check without maximizing the browser window, I mean check with a small browser window so that your content height should be larger than the window..
Then only it will able to scroll y-axis

Comment: I have added update 2, and my content's size is larger that window. Still the same (if i understood you correctly). Also i have checked without maximizing, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you are using as the source of your iframe seems to trigger some sort of scroll event on its parent.

If you wait for it to finish and then run your code to scroll, it will work (sort of).

See the amended fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aLvgx/7

Basically, it's just got a timeout function wrapped around the scrolling:

`setTimeout(function() {
  window.scrollTo(100, 1500);
},1000);`

Comment: yes, i have seen that and changed, but still doesn't work. I ll update my question.

Comment: Yes you're right. It looks like that iframe is doing some resizing? Do you think it could have something to do with the option `adapt=auto`? I tried removing it from the link, but it still resized.

Comment: it sort of works if you wait for the iframe to stop scrolling the parent and wrap the scroll function in a timeout. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/aLvgx/7/

Comment: Great, timeout is a solution. Please add the answer so i can accept it :) Thank you, i can t believe that i have missed resizing.

Comment: thanks, i amended my answer above. omg so excited, my first accepted answer on stackoverflow ;)